# Problem creating a dynamic table with JS using appenChild

Tags: javascript, for-loop, dynamic

I'm trying to create a table, having on the html code just an empty table with an ID. I'm guessing that I should do it with appenChild and for loops, yet, chrome inspector keeps saying there's something wrong and I am just frustrating a bit. This is my first month coding in JS and seems to be kinda impossible sometimes.

Here's my code, in case someone could help me, i'd really apreciate :)

ps- my code references are in spanish, hope is not a problem!

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        td {
            background-color: blueviolet;
            width: 2em;
            height: 2em;
        }
    </style>





    <script>
        window.onload = pintarCarton;

        const MAX_COLUMNAS = 9;
        const MAX_FILAS = 3;
        var tabla = document.getElementById("carton");



        function pintarCarton()
        let tabla = document.getElementById("carton");
        let columna;
        let fila;

        for (let nFilas = 0; nFilas < MAX_FILAS; nFilas++) //Condicion FOR para las FILAS
        { //Abre corchete de accion de lo que hará el FOR relacionado con las FILAS
            fila = document.createElement("tr");
            tabla.appendChild(fila);

            for (let nColumnas = 0; nColumnas < MAX_COLUMNAS; nColumnas++)  //Condicion FOR para COLUMNAS
            {//Abre corchete de accion de lo que hara el FOR relacionado con las columnas
                columna = document.createElement("td");
                tabla.fila.appendChild(columna);

            }//Cierra corchete de accion de lo que hara el FOR relacionado con las columnas

        }//Cierra corchete de accion de lo que hará el FOR relacionado con las FILAS

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="carton"></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Change `tabla.fila.appendChild(columna);` to: `fila.appendChild(columna);`, then it should work.

Comment: also, you're missing curley brackets (`{`) around your function.  It should be `function pintarCarton() { ...... }`.  You dont have brackets on your function.

Comment: Thanks! Just tried it and still not working. Chrome sources says that the problem is in this line: let tabla = document.getElementById("carton");  but i can't see where is the problem :/

Comment: Change those 2 things and it will work. :)

Comment: Ah! Thanks for that! Ill try again :)

Comment: I did work!! Thanks!! :D

Comment: I'm going to post the complete answer...

Comment: if my answer solved your problem and was helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer. (check mark next to the answer) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems, first you're missing brackets around your `pintarCarton()` function, and second, your call to `tabla.fila.appendChild(columna)` should just simply be, `fila.appendChild(columna)`.

The reason being because `fila` is not a property of the `tabla` object, so you can't call, `tabla.fila`. It should simply be `fila.appendChild()`.

Here's the full corrected code: (Run code snippet)

```js
window.onload = pintarCarton;

        const MAX_COLUMNAS = 9;
        const MAX_FILAS = 3;
        var tabla = document.getElementById("carton");



        function pintarCarton() {
            let tabla = document.getElementById("carton");
            let columna;
            let fila;

            for (let nFilas = 0; nFilas < MAX_FILAS; nFilas++) //Condicion FOR para las FILAS
            { //Abre corchete de accion de lo que hará el FOR relacionado con las FILAS
                fila = document.createElement("tr");
                tabla.appendChild(fila);

                for (let nColumnas = 0; nColumnas < MAX_COLUMNAS; nColumnas++)  //Condicion FOR para COLUMNAS
                {//Abre corchete de accion de lo que hara el FOR relacionado con las columnas
                    columna = document.createElement("td");
                    fila.appendChild(columna);

                }//Cierra corchete de accion de lo que hara el FOR relacionado con las columnas

            }//Cierra corchete de accion de lo que hará el FOR relacionado con las FILAS
        }
```

```css
td {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table id="carton"></table>
```